# Devise not showing errors on user creation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, rubygems

I've run into a situation where I'm trying to create my own user outside of the flow of Devise because I need to modify the user model right after creation.

Here's the relevant actions from the controller:

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def resource
    @user || User.new
  end

  helper_method :resource

  def create_user
    @user = User.new email: params[:email]
  end

  def create_password
    @user = User.new email: params[:email], password: params[:password], password_confirmation: params[:password]


    if @user.save
      sign_in @user
      customer = Stripe::Customer.create(description: @user.email, card: params[:stripeToken])
      current_user.stripe_customer_id = customer.id
      Stripe::Charge.create(amount: 5000, currency: "usd", customer: user.stripe_customer_id)
      role = Role.find_by_name("purchased")
      current_user.roles << role
      current_user.save
      redirect_to user_root_url, notice: "You signed up"
    else
      render action: "create_user"
    end
  end
end
```

Our flow is this:

We have a text box on our homepage with a pay button.  User puts their email in, clicks pay button, [Stripe box pops](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout) up, enters CC info, clicks "Buy" and gets directed to the `create_user` page.  This:

```
.wrapper
  %h1 Create Password
  = form_tag create_password_home_url do
    = devise_error_messages!
    = label_tag :email
    = text_field_tag :email, @user.email
    %br
    = label_tag :password
    = password_field_tag :password
    %br
    = hidden_field_tag :stripeToken, params[:stripeToken]
    = submit_tag "Create Password"
```

We ask the user to supply a password and this finishes the account creation from the user side (in the `create_password` action).

Things work great if the `@user` successfully saves, if not, I'm redirected to the "please create a password" form, but I'm not getting the devise errors.  In my testing case, I'm using an email I know exists in the system already.  On our other Devise powered sign up page, Devise nicely tells us about this error.

In trying to debug, I was lead to this code in `DeviseHelper`

```
def devise_error_messages!
    return "" if resource.errors.empty?

    messages = resource.errors.full_messages.map { |msg| content_tag(:li, msg) }.join
    sentence = I18n.t("errors.messages.not_saved",
                      :count => resource.errors.count,
                      :resource => resource.class.model_name.human.downcase)

    html = <<-HTML
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2>#{sentence}</h2>
      <ul>#{messages}</ul>
    </div>
    HTML

    html.html_safe
  end
```

Checking the value of `resource.errors.empty?` is in fact `true`.

Any idea why the errors aren't being added to the resource?

Rails 3.2.1

Ruby 1.9.2

**EDIT**

Helper Functions:

```
def resource_name
  :user
end

def resource
  @resource ||= User.new
end

def devise_mapping
  @devise_mapping ||= Devise.mappings[:user]
end
```

The `resource` is being reported as a `User`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you need to define a `resource` helper method on your (I assume) `HomeController` that returns `@user`.

```
def resource
  @user || User.new
end
helper_method :resource
```

But given that these two actions are in `HomeController` and `resource.errors.empty?` does return `true`, then probably you have a `resource` method defined somewhere that return an object that you may not want.

Comment: I'll update the question with more info, but I do have those helpers defined and the resource is being reported as a `User`

Comment: Well, since your controller doesn't inherit from a Devise one, calling `resource` in `devise_error_messages!` will check errors on an empty `User` object, so either you override `devise_error_messages!` to use `@user` instead of `resource` or you can try my answer :).